How to sort the data in flutter aws packages using graphql api?
Please have a look at my code below.
GraphQLResponse<PaginatedResult> res = await Amplify.API
        .query(
          request: ModelQueries.list(
            type,
            where: whereConditions,
            limit: limit,
          ),
        )
        .response;

I didnt find any sorting parameter, method, class in the aws flutter packages.
I searched for the solution in google and even in flutter amplify git issues.
But I didnt get the proper solution.
I want to sort the incoming results based on a field (column).
Example: If my table has Name, Desc, Stock then I need the results by stock in descending order.
i.e. Items which have higher stock to be first in the list.
